# Write user content to a file from Django

Tags: python, django, file, input, output

Basically my problem is this:
my aim is to save into a a file a description entried by the user into a text input
The file has to be saved with the name of the ISBN

This is my code:

```
descr=request.POST['descr']
filename='/media/'+str(request.POST['isbn'])+'.txt'
f = open( filename, 'w+')
myfile = ContentFile(f)
myfile.write(descr)
myfile.close()
```

Into settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/7/toplibrary/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I don't know why but it doesn't work...any advice?

Comment: why don't you use the MEDIA_URL parm instead of '/media/'?

Comment: for example    MEDIA_URL+str(request.POST['isbn'])+'.txt'

Comment: you can also print into the logs the url where the app is trying to save the file.

Comment: what result do you get? any error or just nothing at all?

Comment: You need to provide a proper filename, you sure this '/media/'...is a right path in your HDrive? I think you should use `MEDIA_ROOT` instead. i.e. `filename = MEDIA_ROOT + str(request.POST['isbn'])+'.txt'`